# Looking for a clever way to sort a set of data

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

I have a set of 80 students and I need to sort them into 20 groups of 4.
I have their previous exam scores from a prerequisite module and I want to ensure that the average of the sorted group members scores is as close as possible to the overall average of the previous exam scores.

Sorry, if that isn't particularly clear.

Here's a snapshot of the problem:

```
Student    Score
AA         50   
AB         45 
AC         80
AD         70
AE         45
AF         55
AG         65
AH         90
```

So the average of the scores here is 62.5. How would I best go about sorting these eight students into two groups of four such that, for both groups, the average of their combined exam scores is as close as possible to 62.5.

My problem is exactly this but with 80 data points (20 groups) rather than 8 (2 groups).

The more I think about this problem the harder it seems.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: "The more I think about this problem the harder it seems" -- in fact, it is NP-Hard. This is the *multi-way partition problem*. An evolutionary algorithm approach would be a reasonable strategy for a problem of your size, and not too hard to implement.

Comment: I'm afraid all of the above is largely alien to me.
I fear I may be in over my depth here....

Answer (score 1):

**One Possible Solution:**

I would try going with a greedy algorithm that starts by pairing each student with another student that gets you closest to your target average. After the initial pairing you should then be able to make subsequent pairs out of the first pairs using the same approach.

After the first round of pairing, this approach leverages taking the average of two averages and comparing that to the target mean to create subsequent groups. You can read more about why that will work for this problem [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115091/is-the-average-of-the-averages-equal-to-the-average-of-all-the-numbers-originall)

**However,**

This will not necessarily give you the optimal solution, but is rather a heuristic technique to solve the problem. One noted example below is when one low value must be offset by three high values to reach the targeted mean. These types of groupings will not be accounted for by this technique. However, if you know you have a relatively normal distribution centered around your targeted mean then I think this approach should give a decent approximation.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there is little reason to think that in the optimal solution the groups of 4 will break into 2 groups of 2 in such a way that the groups of 2 will be close to the target mean. It won't be  uncommon for there to be e.g. a single very low score which needs to be balanced out by 3 high scores in such a way that any pair of those will be far from the average. Still, for some distributions this might be a reasonable heuristic.

Comment: Right, as this is a greedy technique it implies that this may not achieve the globally optimal solution. However, with this problem there is no guarantee that you can partition the students in such a way that the target mean is always met by each group. Instead your overall goal is to minimize error and by choosing the locally optimal groupings at each partition the overall error should be minimal. This method is also very easy to implement and runs with a reasonable execution time of O(n^2) at each partitioning.

Comment: I agree that it is a reasonable heuristic (so +1), and it is somewhat more flexible than mechanically pairing the lowest to the highest, but it isn't the case that the resulting partition minimizes the overall error (however that is measured). It probably is a good first step, which could be followed by a hill-climbing approach which swaps pairs of elements until a local optima is found.

Comment: I see what you mean about this not being a perfect method and excellent idea with the pair swapping.

Answer (score 0):

First sort the goup by score. So it becomes:

```
AH  90
AC  80
.....
AB  45
AE  45
```

Then start combinning the first with the last:

```
(AE, AH, 67.5)
(AB, AC, 62.5)
(AD, AA, 60)
(AG, AF, 60)
```

And so on in the other case you will combine the two by two. First two with the last two.

Another way:

```
 1. Find all the possible groups by 4 students.
 2. Then for every combination of groups find the abs deviation from the average score and SUM it up for the combination of groups.
 3. Choose the combination of groups with the lowest sum.
```

Comment: This is at best a heuristic. Do you have any reason to think that it is a particularly good heuristic? For one thing, it seems likely to behave fairly poorly when the scores are skewed one way or the other rather than falling in a bell-shaped curve.

Comment: There are 1.78 x 10^91 ways to partition 80 students into 20 groups of size 4. Your last paragraph describes an infeasible brute-force approach.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I did think about the top-bottom match option.
However, as John has highlighted, the results certainly aren't optimal:

```
Scores              Students                            Avg.
40  94  40  94      'AE'    'DA'    'AI'    'AR'        67
40  90  40  88      'AK'    'CI'    'AM'    'BP'        64.5
40  85  40  80      'AQ'    'AW'    'AT'    'BD'        61.25
40  79  40  77      'AU'    'BC'    'AV'    'AB'        59
40  76  40  75      'AX'    'CG'    'AZ'    'CQ'        57.75
40  75  40  75      'BF'    'CB'    'BN'    'BQ'        57.5
40  75  40  74      'BR'    'BI'    'CF'    'CZ'        57.25
40  74  40  74      'CK'    'CO'    'CP'    'AL'        57
40  72  41  71      'DB'    'CN'    'AG'    'BO'        56
41  71  42  70      'CD'    'BM'    'AH'    'BS'        56
42  70  42  69      'BG'    'BL'    'CU'    'CX'        55.75
43  68  44  67      'BK'    'CY'    'AD'    'CE'        55.5
44  64  44  64      'BJ'    'CR'    'BZ'    'BY'        54
45  64  45  63      'BW'    'BV'    'CS'    'BE'        54.25
45  62  47  60      'CV'    'CH'    'AC'    'CM'        53.5
47  59  47  58      'BT'    'AY'    'CL'    'AP'        52.75
47  57  48  57      'CT'    'BA'    'BX'    'AS'        52.25
48  56  49  56      'CA'    'AJ'    'AN'    'AA'        52.25
50  55  50  54      'BB'    'AF'    'CJ'    'AO'        52.25
51  52  51  52      'CC'    'BU'    'CW'    'BH'        51.5
```